# Looping on the list of files name in unix

Tags: shell-script, find, filenames

Suppose in unix directory,there are some files placed with same filename but with different extension like

```
abc.001
abc.002
abc.003
```

There can be n number of files.

I need to first get the files from the directory and then iterate on each files.
With the below command I am getting the files but can anyone please help how to iterate on each file and read each file and do processing.?

```
find "/tmp/files/" -name "abc.*" -type f -exec echo {} \;
```

Comment: what kind of processing are you planing to perform?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest:- After I get the list of files I need to iterate on  all files and grep for particular value.

Comment: If the file names are the same save for extensions AND the extensions are 3 byte numbers: `for f in abc.*; do [[ "$f" =~ "abc."[0-9]{3} ]] && echo "Processed: $f"; done`

Answer (score 2):

Why iterate? `grep` takes several file arguments at once, so

```
grep PATTERN abc.*
```

should work.

In case the files are not all in the same directory, using `find` is an option:

```
find /tmp/files -name 'abc.*' -type f -exec grep PATTERN /dev/null {} +
```

The `+` at the end tells `find` to pass as many files as possible to `grep` in one go. The `/dev/null` is to make sure at least 2 files are passed to `grep` so `grep` always outputs the file name for every match. With GNU `grep`, you can use the `-H` (aka `--with-filename`) option instead.